Can you copy field data from multiple entries at once in Keepass?
I have over 100 machines in my Keepass database. I want to somehow export/copy every single machine's IP address.
If I were to do it by copying it machine by machine, it would take me ages. I'd love to copy everyting at once and paste it into a text file.
I don't think I can do that using the context menu as when I select multiple entries and right click on them the options to copy field data are greyed out and inactive:

Is there any other way to accomplish this?
